# Design pattern: Only instanciate class if it is not a duplicate of an already instanciated object

Tags: design-patterns, factory

I have a class `RT` modelling a rooted tree (essentially).

Let's say, I have already an instance `rt1` holding the following tree:

```
   1
  / \
 0   2
```

Now, I *could* construct another instance (`rt2`) holding the following tree:

```
   5
  / \
 4   9
```

However, it is clear that these two trees are isomorphic (i.e. they have the same structure, and are the same up to renaming of nodes). I already have a routine computing whether two rooted trees are isomorphic (so this subproblem is already solved).

Now my question: For my purpose, I'd like a design pattern that prevents the program from actually constructing a new instance for `rt2`, but instead just giving the reference to the element `rt1` (which is already constructed).

On the other hand, consider another tree (`rt3`), namely the following:

```
    1
   / \
  2   5
 /
7
```

The construction routine called for this graph should create a new instance representing this graph (since this is not isomorphic to `rt1`, and - thus - has not been generated up to now).

Is there such a thing?

I looked at the factory pattern, but I'm not sure (factory seems to *always* construct a new element). Can anybode tell me kind of "best-practice" way of solving this particular problem.

Comment: Do you need global access to the object aswell? Singleton might be the way to go then.

Comment: A factory can cache constructed elements and return them instead of constructing new instances. But what would be the arguments of the create() method?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your answer. That was along the lines of my thougts. Is this done "in reality"? Or are there other possibilities (that are more widely used for some reasons)? The arguments to the `create()` method would be (e.g.) the edges of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flyweight pattern.

[image: 1]

In flyweights array you hold all your trees, where tree is of type `ITree`(`Flyweight`). `ConcreteFlyweight` can be called `BinaryTree` or, as your name `RT`. You have to implement equal operation in you tree implementation for order to use in `GetFlyweight` method.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are wanting one instance of an object and want to return that single instance you would use a Singleton. Not exactly sure how you are tying that into creating your tree, but it might be a mix of a Singelton with a Factory. All the patterns you talking about are creational type patterns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern

Here is an description of the Singleton: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you wish to build a prototypical instance. In which case you'd want to use the Prototype Design Pattern.

See: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternPrototype.aspx